# Populate array of unique combinations from three sets of values

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

I am facing a problem regarding a special kind of merging of data's and I hope someone will be able to help me.

I have an array of *x* arrays built according to an undefined number of criteria. Here is an example of the kind of array that I have:

```
array 
  2 => 
    array 
      0 => string 'Body' 
      1 => string 'Face'
  5 => 
    array 
      0 => string '*'
      1 => string '**'
      2 => string '***'
  7 =>
    array 
      0 => string 'Europe'
      1 => string 'Asia'
```

Please note that there can be any number of arrays inside the main array, with any number of values inside each sub-arrays.

I would like to get a final array with all the combinations possible of these 3 arrays separated by a semicolon, for instance:

```
array
  0 => 'Body;*;Europe'
  1 => 'Body;*;Asia' 
  2 => 'Body;**;Europe'
  3 => 'Body;**;Asia'
  4 => 'Body,***;Europe'
  5 => 'Body;***,Asia'
  6 => 'Face;*;Europe'
  7 => 'Face;*;Asia' 
  8 => 'Face;**;Europe'
  9 => 'Face;**;Asia'
  10 => 'Face,***;Europe'
  11 => 'Face;***,Asia'
```

I suppose that I have to iterate recursively throughout these *x* arrays, each of them containing *y* values, but it really causes me a lot of troubles.

As indicated in the title of the post, I'm using PHP.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: are the 2,5,7 portions constant, or do you have a randomish/varaible number of "parent" sections? There's no need for recursion if 2/5/7 are fixed - just a 3-way nested loop will do the trick.

Comment: I think your real problem is the format that your data is in.  Where is the array coming from?  I'd work on getting the data into a sensible format.

Comment: MarcB and Dave : no, datas and portions are not constant unfortunately (it would have been so easy). Therefore, the format has to be a collection of collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is, actually, about [Decart product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of given values sets. That can be implemented with:

```
function decartProductPair($one, $two)
{
   $result=[];
   for($i=0; $i<count($one); $i++)
   {
      for($j=0; $j<count($two); $j++)
      {
         $result[]=array_merge((array)$one[$i], (array)$two[$j]);
      }
   }
   return array_values($result);
}
function decartProduct()
{
   $args   = func_get_args();
   if(!count($args))
   {
      return [];
   }
   $result = array_shift($args);
   while($arg=array_shift($args))
   {
      $result=decartProductPair($result, $arg);
   }
   return $result;
}
```

-so if your test data is:

```
$data = array(
  2 => 
    array(
      0 => 'Body',
      1 => 'Face'
  ),
  5 => 
    array( 
      0 => '*',
      1 => '**',
      2 => '***'
  ),
  7 =>
    array(
      0 => 'Europe',
      1 => 'Asia'
  )
);
```

-then you can easily achieve desired result with:

```
$result = array_map(function($set)
{
   return join(',', $set);
}, call_user_func_array('decartProduct', array_values($data)));
```

Your output will be like:

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "Body,*,Europe"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "Body,*,Asia"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "Body,**,Europe"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "Body,**,Asia"
  [4]=>
  string(15) "Body,***,Europe"
  [5]=>
  string(13) "Body,***,Asia"
  [6]=>
  string(13) "Face,*,Europe"
  [7]=>
  string(11) "Face,*,Asia"
  [8]=>
  string(14) "Face,**,Europe"
  [9]=>
  string(12) "Face,**,Asia"
  [10]=>
  string(15) "Face,***,Europe"
  [11]=>
  string(13) "Face,***,Asia"
}
```

-check this [fiddle](http://3v4l.org/32TmP). Second function, `decartProduct()` added just to simplify usage. In fact, it can be replaced with [`array_reduce()`](https://www.php.net/array_reduce) + `decartProductPair()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something similar to this:

```
<?php
$array = array(4 => array("My","Your"), 5 => array("Dog","Fish","Cat"), 6 => array("is","was"), 7 => array("cool","dumb","nosy"));

function reduce($str,$arr) 
{
 if(count($arr)==0) return $str;
 $first=array_shift($arr);
 $s="";
 foreach($first as $v) $s .= reduce($str.",".$v,$arr);
 return $s;
}

echo(reduce("",$array));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generators:

```
$ cat a.php 
<?php

function decart(array $items) {
        $next = array_slice($items, 1);

        foreach ($items[0] as $item) {
                if (count($next) == 0) {
                        yield [$item];
                } else {
                        foreach (decart($next) as $items) {
                                yield array_merge([$item], $items);
                        }
                }
        }
}


foreach (decart([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]) as $item) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", $item[0], $item[1], $item[2]);
}

$ php a.php 
1 4 7
1 4 8
1 4 9
1 5 7
1 5 8
1 5 9
1 6 7
1 6 8
1 6 9
2 4 7
2 4 8
2 4 9
2 5 7
2 5 8
2 5 9
2 6 7
2 6 8
2 6 9
3 4 7
3 4 8
3 4 9
3 5 7
3 5 8
3 5 9
3 6 7
3 6 8
3 6 9
```